CountIfs Formula to Include Blank cells
I'm working with this current formula below and what I want to do is count cells that are <10 or are blank. How do I update what's in bold below to also include blank cells? Thanks.
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$AQ:$AQ,C9,Sheet2!$BN:$BN,"<10",Sheet2!$CL:$CL,"")

You could try using something like this with the help of HSTACK() function:
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$AQ:$AQ,C9,Sheet2!$BN:$BN,HSTACK("<10",""),Sheet2!$CL:$CL,""))

